# Run adduser interactively with a script password problem

Tags: bash, scripts, password, adduser

I am able to run the adduser command with a script automaticly, but I have no idea how I can get the script to automaticly enter the password hello without needing to type it. Do you have any ideas? The idea of my script is being able to create a new user without interaction with the standard password "hello".